# Mysql Encryption Key

Tags: mysql, encryption, aes

Is it possible to get the `AES_ENCRYPT()` key if i have the original string and the encrypted string?
Any help appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is called a [known-plaintext attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Known-plaintext_attack). Any modern cipher that have known plaintext attack is consider broken.

So, the answer is "no". (or, not yet, unless you count [those academical papers](http://www.cryptosystem.net/aes/))